# Can I directly connect to a MySQL database from AngularJS?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, database-connection

I'd like to connect from AngularJS code to a MySQL database. Is there a way to connect directly or do I need to use something like Node.js or PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is a client-side (browser-side) technology. As such it passes application data to and from the server using HTTP calls (AJAX / JSON).  So you'll need to create web services using node.js or some other server-side tech to access your MySQL data base.